# "cc1: error: /usr/local/include: not a directory" after installing C library

Tags: c, unix, cs50

This is the first time I install a library. I followed the instructions [here](http://cdn.cs50.net/2010/fall/lectures/2/src/cs50.h). It's from an online course on programming.

I'm not very Unix savvy. When I tried to compile one of the sample c files, one that #includes the cs50.h file, I get:

```
cc1: error: /usr/local/include: not a directory
```

Also, if I write `cd /usr/local/include` or `cd /usr/local/lib`, it tells me it's not a directory again, even though when I `ls /usr/local` they both show up.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like your error message it pointing to a relative directory, not an absolute one. Did you forget to put a forward slash somewhere? I think it should be `/usr/local/include`

Comment: @Alex that was a typo, sorry.

Comment: @Mohammad I did have to sudo when I installed the library. Where the instructions say `cp cs50.h /usr/local/include`, I had to use `sudo cp cs50.h /usr/local/include`.

Comment: Sorry I clicked on the delete button by mistake,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the instructions in the header are:

- To compile as a static library on your own system:
- `% gcc -c -ggdb -std=c99 cs50.c -o cs50.o`
- `% ar rcs libcs50.a cs50.o`
- `% rm -f cs50.o`
- `% cp cs50.h /usr/local/include`
- `% cp libcs50.a /usr/local/lib`

<s>Note the use of '%' as a prompt.  It indicates that the operations should be done as root.</s>

Unless your system is misconfigured, you will need to use root privileges to copy the files into the directories under `/usr/local`.  For example, you might use `sudo` as a prefix to the commands:

```
sudo cp cs50.h /usr/local/include
sudo cp libcs50.a /usr/local/lib
```

We can deduce (with fairly high confidence) that you did not already have directories `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib`, and that you now have two files (not directories) called:

- `/usr/local/include` that contains the header cs50.h
- `/usr/local/lib` that contains the static library

You should validate this observation with `ls -l /usr/local` and perhaps `file /usr/local/*`.  Then you should remove the files, create the directories, and copy the files into the newly created directories.

The only thing this explanation does not account for is the missing leading slash in the error message (which originally said '`cc1: error: usr/local/include: not a directory`').  At the moment, I put that down to a transcription error in asking this question. (And a comment and edit confirms that diagnosis.)

Comment: Normally a `#` prompt, not `%`, indicates root.

Comment: @Keith: oh...bother...yes, you're right...'%' means the other sin - using a C Shell.  It isn't the prompt I get...

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have solved the original problem. Though I still had to sudo when copying the files. Now I also get a new error altogether lol. When I `gcc -o f2c.o f2c.c -lcs50`. "undefined symbols"

Comment: @fakaff: which symbols are undefined?  Also, your output file name is aconventional: you'd normally write `gcc -o f2c f2c.c -lcs50` (or, perhaps, `gcc -o f2c.o -c f2c.c`).

Comment: I get: `Undefined symbols:
  "_getfloat", referenced from:
      _main in ccG8nNEz.o
ld: symbol(s) not found`

Comment: @fakaff: since the code in cs50.c defines `GetFloat()` and C is case-sensitive, there will be no `getfloat()` unless you write it.

Comment: @Jonathan D'oh! I changed that to getfloat() about two hours ago, for reasons I no longer remember, and forgot to change it back. Thanks for all the help!